# The Rambam, Moshiach, and the Amidah

Tags: rambam, shemoneh-esrei, messianic-redemption

The last perakim of Mishneh Torah discuss the messianic process. The [11th perek](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm) discusses the role of Moshiach. In particular, the first halachah discusses the "order of operations:"

> א  המלך המשיח עתיד לעמוד, ולהחזיר מלכות בית דויד ליושנה הממשלה הראשונה, ובונה מקדש, ומקבץ נדחי ישראל.  וחוזרין כל המשפטים בימיו, כשהיו מקודם:  מקריבין קרבנות, ועושין שמיטין ויובלות ככל מצותן האמורה בתורה.
>
> The 1) King messiah will arise in the future and return the kinship of the house if David to its ancient kingship, 2) rebuild the temple, and 3) gather in the exiled of Israel. 4) And returns the judgements (courts) in his days like they were before: 5) bringing sacrifices, and making sabbatical and jubilee years like all the commandments conveyed in the Torah.

This seems to establish a clear chronology, and many commentators discuss where the ordering diverges from Talmudic sources (see the back of the Frankel Rambam for explicit examples).

The Anshei Kinesses HaGedolah (Men of the Great Assembly) organized the Amidah, in which we pray for the redemption, among other things. The order they established is: 1) the ingathering of exiles, 2) reestablish our judges and advisors, 3) rebuilding Jerusalem, 4) bringing the messiah and reinstating the Davidic kingship and 5) rebuilding the temple and reinstating sacrifices.

The order we pray in seems distinctly different than that invoked by the Rambam. In fact, one might argue that the prayer order is closer current historical experience: the return of Jews to Israel from around the globe, the resurgence of Torah institutions in Israel, the building and rebuilding of cities throughout the land... According to some, when we cross the point where the majority of Jews are residing in Israel (which will be fairly soon) many dormant laws will come back into effect.

Is there an explanation for why the Rambam diverges from the order in which we pray for redemption? Conversely, is there an explanation for why the Sages instituted an order for prayer at odds with the expected order of redemption?

Comment: `The Anshei Kinesses HaGedolah (Men of the Great Assembly) organized the Amidah` Source? (When you find your source, make sure to clarify what exactly it is referring to; wording? themes? etc.)

Comment: `The order we pray in seems distinctly different than that invoked by the Rambam` Do you have evidence that the order of the berakhot is meant to be chronological? (I assume you have in mind Megillah 17b, but edit that in!)

Comment: `Is there an explanation for why the Rambam diverges from the order in which we pray for redemption` Besides for the aforementioned points, Rambam himself emphasises (Hilkhot Melakhim 12:2) that no one knows the details and order of events if the eschatological age! That seems to obviate your question.

Comment: @mevaqesh except that, as I mentioned, the Talmud itself provides an order for the process and the commentaries go to great lengths to explain the differences.

Comment: I don't know how that relates to any of my above points.

Comment: The Rambam says no one knows the order, and you have provided no reason to think the order of the blessings is indicative of the order it will happen. I don't know what contradiction you think there is here.

Comment: @mevaqesh the Rambam distinguishes between the messianic process (for which he proscribed an order) and the eschatology following that, known as Acharit HaYamim. 12:2 is about the latter, not the former.

Comment: I don't know why you would think that Rambam pr*e*scribes an order for the messianic process, in seeming contradiction to his words in Hilkhot Melakhim. Nor do I understand why the blessings in the Amidah, (even if one were to assume that they correspond to a chronological order) necessarily belong to the messianic category, rather than to the eschatological category (whatever distinction is even intended by this). Regardless, these points should be clarified in the post itself.

Comment: @mevaqesh that's not what that Rambam says. 12:2 says that we don't know which prophecies are using allegorical imagery. That's absolutely NOT saying that the process leading up to moshiach is unknown. Unless your version of the Rambam starts 12:2 in a different place than here: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e512.htm

Comment: ויש מן החכמים שאומרים שקודם ביאת המלך המשיח, יבוא אלייהו.  וכל אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן--לא יידע אדם היאך יהיו, עד שיהיו:  שדברים סתומים הן אצל הנביאים.  גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו, אלא לפי הכרע הפסוקים; ולפיכך יש להם מחלוקת בדברים אלו.  ועל כל פנים, אין סידור הוויית דברים אלו ולא דקדוקן, עיקר בדת I was using the Vilna numbering. Remember to edit any relevant info into the post.